# ImportError: No module named SOAPpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "naturalClient.py", line 9, in <module> from SOAPpy import SOAPProxy
ImportError: No module named SOAPpy
```

I get that when i make

```
from SOAPpy import SOAPProxy
```

in python. I use ubuntu 14.04

Comment: My guess is you still need to download `SOAPpy`.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably not installed SOAPpy - that's why you also won't be able to `import SOAPpy` also

Follow [the official instruction](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SOAPpy#soappy-simple-to-use-soap-library-for-python)

Comment: Command "git clone -q http://github.com/kiroky/SOAPpy.git /home/ryan/src/soappy" failed with error code 128 in None
 i get that error when i but this command  pip install -e "git+http://github.com/kiroky/SOAPpy.git@develop#egg=SOAPpy"

Comment: Then just download [SOAPpy](https://github.com/kiorky/SOAPpy) directly from github and follow steps

Comment: error: Could not find required distribution pytest i get that error when execute the last step